# How to pass exception to the method of the method in Spring Webflow?

Tags: java, spring-webflow

The problem with the transmission of the exceptions in the Spring WebFlow 3

The pre-define the method throw an exception like the following:

```
public class MyBusinessException extends BusinessException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1276359772397342392L;

    private Long min = null;

    private Long max = null;

    public static final String CODE_1 = "code.1.business.exception";

    public static final String CODE_2 = "code.2.business.exception";

    public MyBusinessException (String code, Exception ex) {
        super(code, ex);
    }

    public MyBusinessException (String code) {
        super(code);
    }

    public MyBusinessException (Long min, Long max, final String messageCode) {
        super(messageCode);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

    }

    public Long getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public Long getMax() {
        return max;
    }

}
```

The transition after the capture of an exception in webflow looks like this

```
<transition on-exception="MyBusinessException" to="start" >
            <evaluate expression="actionService.showError(flowExecutionException)" result="flashScope.refreshError"/>
</transition>
```

In action showError would retrieve the message from the exception and the min and max values​​. How to do it. Please help.

```
public String showError(FlowExecutionException flowExecutionException) {
        flowExecutionException.?
        return "someString";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

The **best** way, if you can do it, is to implement/override MyBusinessException's toString() method. Every Exception has a toString() method, so whatever FlowExecutionException you get in your showError method you'll still get a meaningful description of the error in the String.

```
public String showError(FlowExecutionException flowExecutionException) {
    return flowExecutionException.toString();
}
```

A fallback method, e.g. if you don't have access to the code inside MyBusinessException, would be to use the instanceof operator to determine whether MyBusinessException is a valid class, superclass, interface or superinterface of your FlowExecutionException.

```
public String showError(FlowExecutionException flowExecutionException) {
    if (flowExecutionException instanceof MyBusinessException) {
        MyBusinessException usableException = (MyBusinessException)flowExecutionException;

        int min = usableException.getMin();
        int max = usableException.getMax();

        return "MyBusinessException min="+min+", max="+max;

    } else return flowExecutionException.toString();
}
```